# Flexbox creates a lot of whitespace and moves down the object it is affecting

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace

So I am learning to use flexbox and it was working fine untill I tried to use it on a some items that wrapped. When that happened the whole block moved down by the amount of the wrapped object.Just to be clear the top part here above the cars and below the lorem ipsum is the part that has been moved. [image]

As you can see there's a lot of whitespace there and that is not supposed to be there and it wasn't untill I used flexbox. But my goal is to make it wrap just using flexbox (so no float: left trickery). Here's my code. http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 604px) {
    #menu {
        height: 50px;
        width: 99.8%-1px;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -moz-flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99;
        background: linear-gradient(#CC0, #EE0);
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
        border: 1px solid #566;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #444;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    }
    #ida {
        border-right: 1px solid #111;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
    a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    div.top {
        height: 100%;
        width: 75%;
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        border: 5px solid #1F1F1F;
    }
    p {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        margin: 1px;
        color: black;
    }
    .desc {
        display: block;
        top: -31.5%;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #F5F3F3;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 9px 9px;
    }
    .image {
        height: 110%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 9px;
    }
    .foot {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 38.5%;
        position: relative;
    }
    #footext {
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        left: 28%;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        color: grey;
    }
    #Vaerksted {
        height: 110%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
    .Overflow {
        height: 240px;
        width: 99.8%-1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .header {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    h3 {
        margin: 0px
    }
    h4 {
        margin: 0px
    }
    .New {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
        padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;

    }
    .carfs {
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 9px;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .men0img {
        height: 60px;
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
    }
    .del3 {
        width: 38%;
        height: 318px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: -322px;
        left: -12px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    }
    .3delt {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .del1 {
        width: 60%;
        border: 1px solid #C6C8C8;
    }
    .velkommen {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .aabningstider {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .googlemaps {
        height: 159px;
        width: 345px;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .google_maps {
        top: 25px;
        margin-top: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .randlogo {
        height: 56px;
        width: 140px;
        position: relative;
        top: -2px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #Mc {
        margin-bottom: auto;
        height: 110%;
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
    }
    .op {


    }
}
```

Now for my html

```
<div class="op">
    <div class="New">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Nyeste Biler</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flexit">
            <div class="carfs">
                <img src="Car.jpg" class="image">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>
                        - Kilometer: 147000 KM
                        <br> - Geartype: Automatgear
                        <br> - Brænsstoftype: Benzin
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        - Farve: Sølv metal
                        <br> - Antal døre: 5 Døre
                        <br> - Type: Stationcar
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carfs">
                <img src="Car1.jpg" class="image">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>
                        - Kilometer: 153000 KM
                        <br> - Geartype: Manuel
                        <br> - Brænsstoftype: Benzin
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        - Farve: Sort metal
                        <br> - Antal døre: 5 Døre
                        <br> - Type: Stationcar
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carfs">
                <img src="MC.jpg" class="image" id="Mc">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>
                        - Kilometer: 72000 KM
                        <br> - Hestekræfter: 96Hk
                        <br> - Brænsstoftype: Benzin
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        - Farve: Rød
                        <br> - Antal døre: 0 Døre
                        <br> - Type: Standard
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carfs">
                <img src="AC.jpg" class="image">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>
                        - Kilometer: 220000 KM
                        <br> - Geartype: Automatgear
                        <br> - Brænsstoftype: Benzin
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        - Farve: Hvid
                        <br> - Antal døre: 4 Døre
                        <br> - Type: Autocamper
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, we can only guess without seeing your code. Answers would be hit and miss. But try this on flex container: `align-content: flex-start`.

Comment: Did not work, but have now added code.

Comment: Are you able to post enough code to reproduce the problem? The code you posted is limited and doesn't identify any problems.

Comment: do jsfiddle and paste all relevant code here. now we are unable to help.

Comment: I added all the code.

Comment: Can't reproduce problem. Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/pqyuqaq0/

Comment: I fixed the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised Answer**

The problem isn't the flexbox.

The problem is that you have a `div` – `.del3` – which is relatively positioned upward.

Because `.del3` is [***relatively*** positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning), adjacent elements will respect its original place in the layout.

*The large white space represents the location of `del3` before you moved it up with `top: -322px`.*

Here's your layout with `top: -322px` commented out:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy/4/)

There are many better ways to accomplish this layout.

There's [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), of course.

Or you could take `del3` out of the flow with [**absolute positioning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), so adjacent boxes ignore its existence. (Make sure to set the parent – `.3delt` – to `position: relative`.)

Or you could simply apply `float: left` to the first div in the row:

```
.del1 {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #C6C8C8;
    float: left; /* NEW */
}

.del3 {
    width: 38%;
    height: 318px;
    /* float: right; */
    /* position: relative; */
    /* top: -322px; */
    /* left: -12px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy/5/)

---

**Original Answer**

<s>Try removing or adjusting `height: 240px` from:</s>

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px)
   .Overflow {
             height: 240px;
             width: 99.8%-1px;
             overflow: hidden;
             margin: auto;
    }
```

Also, the `width` rule has a syntax error. Try this: `width: calc(98.8% - 1px);`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy/1/)

Comment: I tested the code before posting my answer. It works in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0eccdumy/1/

Comment: Under the big lorem ipsum is still a lot of whitespace even after your fix. Maybe it's because i'm using chrome. But nevertheless i want a permanent and universal fix.

Comment: My apologies. I was focusing on the gap at the top. Didn't even see the gap at the bottom. Reviewing.

Comment: Sorry i might not have been clear i'll just edit it, but thanks for the fix for the gap at the top :) I really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: Thank you oh so much. I know it's a bit of a newbie question, but really did not know how to work with flexbox and I thought that was the problem. You have given me a lot of insight into this problem and have helped in any future endevours. Thank you very much sir.